# Existence of variable-independent analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $U$ be a connected open subset of $\mathbb{C^n}$, with coordinates $x_1, \dots, x_n$. Let $f, g$ be two holomorphic functions on $U$. Consider $I = (f, g)$, the ideal generated by $f$ and $g$ in the ring of holomorphic functions on $U$. Is it true that there exists a non-zero $h \in I$ that is independent of the first complex variable $x_1$ (that is, $\partial h / \partial x_1 \equiv 0$)?

**EDIT (15/3/22)**: we further assume that the ideal $I = (f, g)$ is a prime ideal.

**EDIT (15/3/22)**: we further assume that the ideal $I = (f, g)$ is not a principal ideal.

A local version of the result would be satisfying as well: for any point $p \in U$ there exist a connected open subset $V \subseteq U$ such that $p \in V$, and a non-zero holomorphic function $h$ on $V$ in the ideal $(f|_V, g|_V)$. Is this true?

Comment: For $n=1$, the Cauchy-Riemann equations (for $h$) tells you that this is true only if $I = \mathcal{H}(U)$, the set of all holomorphic functions.

Comment: Didier gave a (kind of) trivial counterexample. So the more interesting question would be: *What are conditions on $f, g$ that such a $h$ exists (locally)?* Clearly such ideal exist, for example if one of $f$ or $g$ is independent of $x_1$. But if both have $x_1$ as a factor (eg $f = x_1x_2, g = x_1x_3$ you will have no chance.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! As you have noticed already, this question is a work in progress and, as suggested by @red_trumpet , we are looking for the sweet conditions for the result to be somehow true :)

Comment: @Didier your counterexample is correct. Please look at the edited question, as the additional hypothesis excludes your scenario. Thank you!

Comment: Changing the problem after accepting an answer is not the best use of the site. If you realize that you're interested in a variant of the question you asked here after getting and accepting an answer, the best thing to do would be to ask a new question with the additional conditions you're interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $U = \Delta^n$ be a unit polydisk, $f(z_1,\ldots,z_n)=g(z_1,\ldots,z_n)=z_1$. Then $I = (z_1)$ does not contain any non-zero holomorphic function independent from $x_1 = \mathrm{Re}(z_1)$ (even locally around zero, such a function cannot exist).